# How to use a linear model to predict y from x

Tags: r, lm

I've fit a regression model to my data that gives a good r2.

```
fit <- lm(time ~ poly(ladder,3), data=red.corr)
```

In my data frame I've got a column with containing the "ladder" measurement. I'd like to use this regression model to predict the value of "time".

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: In order to predict the response values use, well, `predict(fit)`.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I use predict to predict values of "time" using values of "ladder" that weren't in the original red.corr dataset?

Comment: 1) Create a dataframe with the new values: `new <- data.frame(ladder = <new values>)` 2) `predict(fit, newdata = new)`.

Answer (score 3):

`lm` fits a *linear* model, not a *log* model.

That said, your `fit` object contains an element called `fitted.values` which contains the mean fitted value for each observation in the input dataframe.  The online doc should give you all you need.

Comment: Thank you, I'm getting there with using *predict* now. Could I please ask what you would suggest using instead of lm for a log model?

Answer (score 0):

*predict.lm* expects a data frame that contains (at least) all the columns with the same names as the data frame used for training, even when there is only one predictor variable.

Example with the builtin data set *mtcars*:

```
fit <- lm(mpg ~ disp, mtcars)
x <- seq(min(mtcars$disp), max(mtcars$disp), by=5)
y <- predict.lm(fit, data.frame(disp=x))
```

Comment: Thanks, I've applied this to my data to test if it can predict values of "ladder" from "time", but it just seems to return fitted values of "time". predict.lm(fit, data.frame(time = red.corr$time)). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Mike Your formula specifies that *time* is to be predicted. If you want *ladder* to be predicted from *time*, you must turn the formula around. Beware that *lm* does an ordinary least squares fit, which -unlike an orthogonal least squares fit- treats x and y differently.

Comment: Ahh ok thank you. I wanted to predict it both ways. Thanks